# How to implement Dispose when a class has multiple members

Tags: .net, vb.net, idisposable

How to implement dispose of a class, that has objects as members which don't implement IDisposable?

Please refer example below to know what I mean:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Implements IDisposable

    private emp as EmpClass
    private dept as DeptClass

    ' EmpClass and DeptClass doesn't implemented IDisposable interface. 

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
       If Not Me.disposedValue Then
          If disposing Then
            emp = Nothing  ' --> Can't call Dispose method so I set to null
            dept = Nothing ' --> Can't call Dispose method so I set to null
          End If
       End If
      Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

From above, all are managed objects, I can do necessary updates. so please suggest is that code ok.

**Edited**

When I have tried to create an instance of MyClass, compiler gives me an error I must implement IDisposable. Following is my calling code.

```
Using ctx = MyFactory.CreateMyClass()
     'DO Something
End Using
```

Comment: The question is: Why do you implement `IDisposable` at all?

Comment: Good question, I appended my actual question above, to answer your question.

Comment: Follow-up question: Why do you want to use your class with an `Using` statement?

Comment: Well, Initially, I have thought to limit scope of this instance so written Using statement, and then started writing code to address issues (like IDisposable). But it looks I don't need Using statement here, and now all issue resolved. However there is a task pending in my mind why can't I use Using..

Comment: Maybe you're thinking *I want to use a `Using` statement so I implement `IDisposable`* instead of *I implement `IDisposable` so I should use a `Using` statement*. Or maybe the use of the class has a limited, specific scope and you want to have something happen at the end of this scope? A common usecase I've seen a lot is e.g. a class that changes the cursor to the WaitCursor in its constructor, and changes it back to the previous cursor in the `Dispose` method. This allows for something `Using New WaitCursor() ... Stuff that happen while wait cursor is shown ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx):

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.
>   The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a
>   managed object when that object is no longer used. However, it is not
>   possible to predict when garbage collection will occur. Furthermore,
>   the garbage collector has no knowledge of unmanaged resources such as
>   window handles, or open files and streams.

So if your classes don't use streams, files or unmanaged objects, then there is no need to call Dispose or implement IDisposable.
other thing that can be in dispose is removing no longer needed listeners